# Uniqueness of solution to nonlinear first-order ODE in non-standard form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I have an ODE of a reasonably simple form:
$$
-x(y')^2 + 2yy' + x = 0 \qquad \qquad (\ast)
$$
for $y$ only assumed to be a differentiable function of $x$ (note: not necessarily $C^1$!) The proof I saw took another derivative and then used some reduction of order to get something separable. I found the solution to $(\ast)$ with my regularity assumption through doing a substitution, getting a separable DE, solving it, etc. And even then, I already knew the form of the solution, so I wasn't particularly surprised. But someone pointed out that I didn't need to actually grind out the solution, because I could check the pretty-much-known solution satisfied the DE, and then with suitable initial conditions (also known) a uniqueness theorem takes over.

However, it's not clear to me what theorem to use. In principle, I could make the substitution and then apply the Picard–Lindelöf theorem to get the uniqueness for the new ODE, but the substitution still feels like inspired magic (it kinda is: I just tried something at random, and was surprised when it worked). Using uniqueness also feels like magic, but of a different sort. At the very least, the solution is well-motivated. So

> What uniqueness result for ODEs can I apply to $(\ast)$ directly?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but we can use quadratic formula to solve for $y'$

$$y' = \frac{y\pm\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}{x} \equiv f(y,x)$$

which does not allow for $x=0$ to be in the domain. Then taking the derivative of the right hand side w.r.t. $y$

$$\partial_y f (y,x) = \frac{1}{x} \pm \frac{y}{x\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}$$

This derivative is always bounded w.r.t. $y$ for both solutions (take the interval of existence to be some predetermined neighborhood away from $0$ and this bound is even uniform), so $f$ is Lipschitz in $y$, therefore a unique solution for the problem with prescribed initial conditions exists.

Comment: Hmm, that's nice. I am looking at a solution on all of $\mathbb{R}$, though, so the issue of looking at $x=0$ is a real one. Perhaps just knowing this plus the requirement that $y$ extends continuously to $x=0$ and is differentiable there is enough?

Comment: @DavidRoberts I wouldn't recommend it. The singular point is baked into the equation from the get-go, kind of like how we needed to use the method of Froebenius in the linear case if there was a zero attached to the highest order derivative term.

Comment: @DavidRoberts what was the solution you found? I'd like to take a look at it to see what its behavior is, if it's not too much trouble to type up your solution.

Comment: @DavidRoberts actually I just thought of something. You $\mathbf{definitely}$ lose uniqueness if you include $0$ in your domain, but you will most likely have a unique, "most physical" solution in the form of a [viscosity solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity_solution). This solution isn't necessarily $C^1$ like you say but it's worth investigating.

Comment: Does it help if I say the derivative is zero at $x=0$, and that I know $y\leq0$ there as well?

Comment: the method I used is [here](https://thehighergeometer.wordpress.com/2019/09/23/the-only-curve-with-a-unique-focus-is-the-parabola/), starting after the phrase "Murshed derives the relation", though I can't guarantee I didn't implicitly use slightly more regularity than I intended.

Answer (score 0):

The $y$-axis is singular for this differential equation, thus excluded from the domain. For $x\ne 0$ multiply with $x$ and complete the square to get
$$
-(xy'-y)^2+x^2+y^2=0.
$$
Set $y(x)=xu(x)$, then the reduced $$x^2u'(x)^2=1+u(x)^2\implies u'(x)=\pm\frac1x\sqrt{1+u(x)^2}$$ 
is clearly Lipschitz in each branch. There are no points where the term under the root is zero, so no differentiable solution can switch branches.

The equation $A^2=1+B^2$ can be parametrized by the hyperbolic functions, here as $xu'(x)=\pm\cosh(v(x))$, $u(x)=\sinh(v(x))$. As $v(x)=\sinh^{-1}(u(x))$ is well-defined and thus differentiable, we also get
$$
u'(x)=\cosh(v(x))v'(x)\implies xv'(x)=\pm 1.
$$
As $\cosh(v)\ge1$ there are no points with an ambiguous situation in cancelling $\cosh(v)$ where the solution could switch to a constant solution for some time. So $$y(x)=\pm x\sinh(\ln x+c)=Cx^2-\frac1{4C},~~ C=\pm2e^{c},$$ is the full solution set.

Comment: And yet $y= x^2 - \frac14$ is a solution....  (and more generally $\frac{A}{2}s^2 - \frac{1}{2A}$) I was really after a theorem that would guarantee uniqueness _without_ solving the thing, since two people have independently asked why I didn't just use that together with the previously known quadratic solution, instead of sitting down and solving it.

Comment: You were right, there was an error in this solution. // To the second point, it is a valid method to transform the equation in an equivalent manner to find expressions where the theory can be applied more directly. It is then just inertia to want to complete the solution method from the transformed equation, partially as check for the correctness of the transformation.